# Eclipse delete or select whitespace to right of cursor until next text (NOT EOL)

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse 4.5.2, is there any key (sequence) that will select the whitespace from the cursor to the next text, or the whitespace between two items of text? For example, if after editing I am left with:

```
if (variable !=               value)
```

I'd like to select the whitespace to quickly change this to

```
if (variable != value)
```

without having to press shift-right 14 times to select that whitespace.

Note that this question has nothing to do with end-of-line whitespace. Also, I could use the formatter, but don't want to apply it to the whole file. I also know I can have formatter fix up just the edited lines when I save the file, but I want a more current change than waiting until save.

The only other solution I could think of is a macro with Home,shift-End,ctrl-shift-f to format just the line, but that leaves the cursor at the end of the line, which means I still need to cursor a bunch of times to continue editing.

Comment: Is this windows, linux, mac? You could use alt + arrow-left on mac to navigate faster, ctrl + arrow as I recall on linux/win.

Comment: shift-ctrl-arrow appears to do what I want. I tried the different modifiers, but not together. please put this in an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> to select the empty space and delete the text on windows/linux, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> on mac.